# Connect-SPOService using App ID and App Secret

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

In SharePoint Online Powershell, is it possible to connect SPOService using App ID and App Secret instead of passing user name and password

Comment: any particular use for SPO shell ? you can do it easily in PnP PowerShell

Comment: @GautamSheth In PnP PowerShell "Set-SPOSite $siteUrl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0" cmd is not available. It is only available in SharePoint Powershell. Is there any alternate for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can set the `DenyAddAndCustomizePages` property via PnP PowerShell.

Its slightly different compared to the OOTB SPO management shell.

You can use the below code to achieve that:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com -AppId <App id> -AppSecret <app-secret>
Set-PnPTenantSite -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test -NoScriptSite:$false
```

Reference - [Set-PnPTenantSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnptenantsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thank you for Sharing this command. I tried this, even though my app id has tenant level full control I am getting (401) Unauthorized error. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: can you try connecting to admin site with `Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com -AppId <App id> -AppSecret <app-secret>` and then run the `Set-PnPTenantSite`  and check ? Also, can you also check with user context as well after that ?

Comment: Thank you @GautamSheth. I have connected to admin site and updated the other site, now without any error I am able to update the site.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same but it is throwing me an error "**System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.**".
What kind of graph api permission required in the App to use these commands?
Here is the code what I am using in PnP C#. It is throwing error when using "tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();".

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(Helper.requestAdminUrl, Constants.AppClientId, Constants.AppClientSecrete))
                {
                    var tenant = new Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant(clientContext);

                    foreach (string s in siteCollectionUrl)
                    {
                        Helper.WriteException("SetUpDenyAddAndCustomizePages, Applying on URL " + s);
                        var siteProperties = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(s, true);
                        tenant.Context.Load(siteProperties);
                        tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();

                        siteProperties.DenyAddAndCustomizePages = Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.DenyAddAndCustomizePagesStatus.Disabled;
                        var operation = siteProperties.Update();
                        tenant.Context.Load(operation, op => op.IsComplete, op => op.PollingInterval);
                        tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();

                        // this is necessary, because the setting is not immediately reflected after ExecuteQuery
                        while (!operation.IsComplete)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(operation.PollingInterval);
                            operation.RefreshLoad();
                            if (!operation.IsComplete)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();
                                }
                                catch (System.Net.WebException webEx)
                                {
                                    Helper.WriteException("Error when applying SetUpDenyAddAndCustomizePages : " + webEx.Message, webEx);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Helper.WriteException("SetUpDenyAddAndCustomizePages, Applied on URL " + s);
                    }

                }
```